# For react-native app, how do I choose which java version I should put in the path?

Tags: java, android, linux, react-native

I'm trying out React/react-native for the first time by following this [tutorial](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html). The set up was much more arduous than I thought it would be when I started, or I made it harder for myself, time will tell. Either way, I got to the point that the directions said I should run `react-native run-ios` only to find that you can't make an ios app on Linux. That makes sense, I just never thought of it before.

To make a long story short, after following tutorials like this [one](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html), this [one](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html), this [one](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html), this [one](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html), this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771439/installing-and-using-android-studio-with-virt-on-ubuntu-16-04) and a few more to hopefully one day get `react-native run-android` to work, I've run into one, I'm hoping, last error message:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I did some searching to see what I should put in here and came across a couple [helpful](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) [links](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/).

And I ran `which java` to see which java I already had on my system, this is what I found:

`which java`

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.9-jre-headless
 * openjdk-9-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

**Briefly, what is the difference?**

***Which do I choose and why?***

Comment: Suggest : `openjdk-8-jre-headless` (or openjdk-9-jre-headless) . The gcj packages are for other purposes.